# Recode a vector of binary factors in R as a dummy variable (0, 1)

Tags: r

I have a vector (really a column of a data frame) that looks like this:

```
data$outcome
[1] Good Good Good Good Poor
Levels: Good Poor
```

Here is the `str` on it:

```
str(data$outcome)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "Good","Poor": 1 1 1 1 2
```

I don't want 1's and 2's as in `as.numeric(data$outcome)
[1] 1 1 1 1 2`

I know you are not supposed to dummy-code the variables "manually" for regression, and I know about {psych} `dummy.code()`, which returns a matrix. I understand that I could use something like `model.matrix()` on the data.frame:

```
data$outcome <- model.matrix(lm(s100b ~ outcome, data))[,2]
```

Not nice...

Isn't there something like `dummify(data$outcomes)` somewhere in R? Please refrain from easy jokes...

Comment: `as.numeric(data$outcome) - 1` ...? (Or, of course, `1 - (as.numeric(data$outcome) - 1)`, if that's the way you want things coded.)

Comment: Thank you. This should do it!

Comment: Great. Glad that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I slightly prefer

```
data$isGood <- as.numeric(data$outcome == 'Good')
```

because it is a bit more explicit / less opaque, and would still work even if someone added a new level 'Awesome' to the factor.